# como retorno variavel dentro de uma função

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, funções

function getPeson () {
const nome1 = 'vagner';
const nome2 = 'jessica';

return nome1, nome2;
}

console.log(getPeson());

Comment: `return` só retorna um valor, o que estiver depois da virgula não será retornado. Pode resolver isso com array `return [nome1, nome2];`

Answer (score -2):

Você poderia concatenar se for o caso de ser duas string seria assim:

```
return nome1 + " " + nome2;
```

Ou se for o javascript ES6 também pode se utilizar [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```
 return `${nome1} ${nome2}`;
```